# Change display when conditional met

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple countdown button that displays a paragraph when it reaches 0.  The countdown button works, but the paragraph isn't displayed at 0.  My code is below.  Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thanks! 
Also, I know it's not the cleanest or most efficient code but I'm just doing this to practice my Javascript.

```js
function countdown(){
  var currentVal = document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML;
  var newValue = 0;
  if (currentVal > 0){
    newValue = currentVal - 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = newValue;
  if (currentVal = 0){
    var vacation = document.getElementById("vacation");
    vacation.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#vacation{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Days until vacation</h1>
<button id="countdown" onclick="countdown()">10</button>
<p id="vacation">Time for vacation woo!</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

In javascript you should use `===` for comparisons.
Also, I suggest that you parse the currentValue as an integer, because `.innerHTML` returns a string.

So replace `if (currentVal = 0){` with `if (currentVal === 0){` 
and use `var currentVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML);` and it should work!

```js
function countdown(){
  var currentVal = parseInt(document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML); // integer parsing
  var newValue = 0;
  if (currentVal > 0) {
    newValue = currentVal - 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = newValue;
  if (currentVal === 0){ // currentVal is equal to newValue (and they are both integers) so you can use either of them
    var vacation = document.getElementById("vacation");
    vacation.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#vacation{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Days until vacation</h1>
<button id="countdown" onclick="countdown()">10</button>
<p id="vacation">Time for vacation woo!</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now.

Comment: you mentioned above use `if (currentVal === 0){` and used `if (newValue === 0){` in the code...?

Comment: It's probably better to set currentVal with a parseInt() call in the first place.

Comment: Yeah I missed that, I updated my answer to be more detailed

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a wrong conditional statement. There is an assignment instead of comparison. So, change to `if (newValue === 0) {`.

Comment: Also, you probably want to compare the `newValue`, so you'd have `if (newValue === 0)`

Comment: Sure. It's a typo

Comment: Thank you both!  I applied both changes and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a wrong conditional statement if (currentVal === 0) {.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the assignment operator instead of comparison operator for checking `currentVal`.  See updated snippet:

```js
function countdown(){
  var currentVal = document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML;
  var newValue = 0;
  if (currentVal > 0){
    newValue = currentVal - 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = newValue;
  if (currentVal == 0){
    var vacation = document.getElementById("vacation");
    vacation.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#vacation{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Days until vacation</h1>
<button id="countdown" onclick="countdown()">10</button>
<p id="vacation">Time for vacation woo!</p>
```